# How to get the properties of a Security Group in AD?

Tags: active-directory

I need to get domain name, scope (Universal/local) of a Security Group in AD.

Can you provide some information about it?

Answer (score 0):

The information is given by  attribute `groupType` as explained in [Microsoft documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675935%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to get that in a C# program. Currently I used param ($groupName) import-module activedirectory get-adgroup $groupName to get the group properties.

Comment: Do you want to use in in C# or in PowerShell ?